# How to fix WINE NSIS Error?

Tags: wine

I installed the WineHQ Staging branch from this page: https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

However,  when I open a file ".exe" by Wine, I get an NSIS error; but I can't fix it.

[image: image here]

What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The executable you are trying to start is not passing a -self test- check. That means the program itself feels there is something wrong, could be a damaged download or DRM.

As it says in the notice: "Contact the installer's author to obtain a new copy".

More on this on the [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Why_do_I_get_NSIS_Error%3F) page. It has a final thing to say:

> **Final options**
>
> As a last resort, the installer can be executed even though it's corrupted. To bypass the corruption test, **pass /NCRC on the command line**. To do so, go to Start->Run, type cmd and hit Enter. A black console window should open. Drag the installer into the window, hit Space and type /NCRC. Hit Enter again and the installer should start. This is not recommended!